# Does 'Worms checkers' sound natural in the following context?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-choice

> There is a fish factory in which there are 2 people who check the fish to find worms in them.

Would it sound natural if I call them 'worms checkers'?

Comment: I think you mean "worms" (little slithery creatures) not "warms" (plural of 'warm' which is the opposite of 'cool')

Comment: You could call them 'worm checkers', though there may be a more technical term used within the factory.

Comment: If people have worms they check the fish?! Or do they _check to see if the **fish** have worms_?

Comment: Thank you for the correction, it was a typo. It should be WORMS. I edited my question.

Comment: Did you create that sentence yourself? If you did, what exactly do you want to know–whether the noun "checker" can be tagged to any noun, e.g. **spell checker**, **grammar checker**, **plagiarism checker**

Comment: Yes, I did. I wasn't sure if the word 'checker' is correct and natural to be used in this context of examination of meat.

Comment: Have you ever heard of someone inspecting fresh (presumably) fish for worms? The job title **worm checker** (note that "worm" must be singular) sounds very off-putting and unpleasant. Workers examine/check the meat, sounds much better to me already. I don't think people can be called "checkers" they're often called inspectors or testers. There's probably a more technical term for someone who does that kind of work.

Comment: That's why I was doubtful about the term. No terms in English in that place. Worm inspectors sounds ok and respectful?

Comment: You need to add @ before a username, I received no notification in my inbox. I came back to see if the question had been improved, if some details had been added. Unfortunately, I see none. "Worm inspectors sounds ok and respectful?" it sounds like someone's job  is to inspect the worms not the food itself, in this case the meat.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thanks for your feedback. I edited my question and got a satisfying answer to it. Thank you.

Comment: There is a specific worker for fish-meat inspection (all their job is to find and remove those parasites). I would not argue with you about it, it would be meaningless. https://carsoe.com/media/5mjh0hau/candling-tables-4.jpg

Comment: Clarification: As far as I am aware, there is no such job as  "worm inspector"  in any meat processing plant. It's either checking or inspecting the meat, this would include any irregularities or deviations in color, smell, and size. Why just "worms"? When fish has gone off, you don't need to check it for worms, you can smell the stench from a mile off

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it isn't quite correct to say "worm**s** checkers".

Usually when making a plural compound noun, the plural "**s**" only appears on the last noun.  So, in your example, that would be "worm checkers". This is similar to compound nouns like coffee experts, apple pickers, grave diggers, ticket inspectors, or book binders, etc.

And yes, "**worm checkers**" will be understood as people who check for worms.  However you could also say "**worm inspectors**", which sounds a bit more formal, more like an official job title. I see no real problem with using the word "**checkers**" in this way, though. It's perfectly understandable.

> ***checker***, n.1
>
> One who checks.
>
> 1. A reprover, rebuker, fault-finder; a controller.

Source: OED.com

Perhaps a more formal title would be better though. **Fish parasite inspector** sounds good to me, and less ambiguous.

Comment: but it doesn't work like apple picker as i first thought of somebody checking the worms for problem, How about fish checkers?

Comment: @WemdyG - the similarity I was referring to here is the use of the plural only on the last part of the compound noun.  Given the context, I didn't have any problem understanding what the OP meant by worm checker.  Perhaps a more formal title would be better though. Fish parasite inspector sounds good to me, and less ambiguous.

Comment: You can add this link, to your answer: 
https://carsoe.com/seafood-processing/products/candling-tables/